# Ignoring any 'bin' directory on a git project

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory structure like this:

```
.git/
.gitignore
main/
  ...
tools/
  ...
...
```

Inside main and tools, and any other directory, at any level, there can be a 'bin' directory, which I want to ignore (and I want to ignore everything under it too). I've tried each of these patterns in .gitignore but none of them work:

```
/**/bin/**/*
/./**/bin/**/*
./**/bin/**/*
**/bin/**/*
*/bin/**/*
bin/**/*
/**/bin/* #and the others with just * at the end too
```

Can anyone help me out? The first pattern (the one I think should be working) works just fine if I do this:

```
/main/**/bin/**/*
```

But I don't want to have an entry for every top-level directory and I don't want to have to modify .gitignore every time I add a new one. There are also files and directories that have the substring 'bin' in their names, **which I want to keep**.

This is on Windows using the latest msysgit.

Comment: Probably somebody will find as helpful: if you have few repositories and each has the same .gitignore file, you can put it into "common" location and launch > git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global The last parameter is path to the common location. P.S. I'm new to git and not sure if that is 'best practice' recommendation. So please let me know if you should not want to do that. Thank you.

Comment: The `**` syntax seems now (March 2013, git 1.8.2) officially documented: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16165581/6309)

Comment: If anyone wants to read the most up-to-date version of the actual manual page, see [gitignore(5) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Comment: friendlier option if you're tired of reading essays for one line's worth of information https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore#git-ignore-patterns

Comment: Possibly worth noting, when creating a global ignore file, it's beneficial to name it `~/.cvsignore`. Other version control systems use this name, making it even more "global".

Answer (score 2137, accepted):

Before version 1.8.2, `**` didn't have any special meaning in the `.gitignore`. As of 1.8.2 git supports `**` to mean zero or more sub-directories (see [release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt)).

The way to ignore *all* directories called `bin` anywhere below the current level in a directory tree is with a `.gitignore` file with the pattern:

```
bin/
```

In the `man` page, there an example of ignoring a directory called `foo` using an analogous pattern.

If you already have any `bin` folders in your git index which you no longer wish to track then you need to remove them explicitly. Git won't stop tracking paths that are already being tracked just because they now match a new `.gitignore` pattern. Execute a folder remove (**rm**) from index only (**--cached**) recursivelly (**-r**). Command line example for root bin folder:

```
git rm -r --cached bin
```

Comment: Starting with git 1.8.2, git will accept `**` in `.gitignore` files (source: [1.8.2 changelog](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt))

Comment: is `bin` the same of `bin/` ?

Comment: @Nisba, they are different, `bin` will ignore files named bin, while `bin/` is for directories named bin

Comment: since I fell over this: folder name in git-command IS case sensitive :) "bin !=Bin" - maybe I spare someone a few minutes by this hint :)

Comment: In windows10 you cannot create a .gitignore file, you have to create a gitignore.txt and then run ren gitignore.txt .gitignore in command prompt to create this file

Comment: So what is the difference between `**.thing/` and `.thing/` in top level gitignore assuming using git 1.8.2 or greater?

Comment: @shabby not entirely true. You can actually create a `.gitignore` file if you have displaying file extensions enabled. At that point you simply remove the ".txt" from the end when naming the file.Also, when renaming, it only works if you do a "Save As" in whatever program, and either surround .gitignore in quotes for the filename, or select "All files (*.*)" in the "Save as type" dropdown.

Comment: Is this the same for any file? Meaning if I had a file named "foo.txt" that I wanted to ignore anywhere. I could just put `foo.txt/` into my .gitignore and it would be ignored anywhere?

Comment: Are **/bin/ and bin/ equal?

Comment: *I actually had to do `git rm -r --cached **/bin`

Answer (score 531):

The `.gitignore` of your dream seems to be:

```
bin/
```

on the top level.

Comment: put it in gitignore_global

Comment: @GAlexander, why would one want to globally ignore bin/ directories? They often have versioned content. And global ignore will not affect other users of the repository.

Answer (score 297):

I think it is worth to mention for git beginners:

> If you already have a file checked in, and you want to ignore it, **Git
>   will not ignore the file if you add a rule later**. In those cases, you
>   must untrack the file first, by running the following command in your
>   terminal:
>
> `git rm --cached`

So if you want add to ignore some directories in your local repository (which already exist) after editing .gitignore you want to run this on your root dir

```
git rm --cached -r .
git add .
```

It will basically 'refresh' your local repo and unstage ignored files.

See:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm,

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Comment: if I usually do a `git add -A` on my commits, can I use this instead? and can I replace the dot with -A on the first line too?

Answer (score 76):

The `**` never properly worked before, but since [git 1.8.2 (March, 8th 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt#L85-L88), it seems to be explicitly mentioned and supported:

> The patterns in `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files **can have `**/`, as a pattern that matches 0 or more levels of subdirectory**.
>
> E.g. "`foo/**/bar`" matches "`bar`" in "`foo`" itself or in a subdirectory of "`foo`".

In your case, that means this line might now be supported:

```
/main/**/bin/
```

Answer (score 51):

```
[Bb]in/
```

matches both upper and lower case

Comment: `[B]in/` to be the only upper case

Comment: How to let only `Bin` folder ignore and let `bin` commit to git?    `[B]in/` will both commit `Bin` and `bin`.

Comment: This should do it, @Gank:
    `Bin/`  
    `!bin/`

Answer (score 42):

**Step 1: Add following content to the file .gitignore.**

```html
# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# Visual Studio 2015 cache/options directory
.vs/
```

**Step 2: Make sure take effect**

If the issue still exists, that's because settings in **.gitignore** can only ignore files that were originally **not tracked**. If some files have already been included in the version control system, then modifying **.gitignore** is invalid.
To solve this issue completely, you need to open **Git Bash** or **Package Manager Console** (see screenshot below) to run following commands in the repository root folder.

```html
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m "Update .gitignore"
```

[image: PM console]
Then the issue will be completely solved.

Answer (score 37):

I didn't see it mentioned here, but this appears to be case sensitive. Once I changed to /Bin the files were ignored as expected.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the original question which was explicitly about `bin`, not `Bin`.

Comment: Though not an answer, it does add to the completeness for others searching on the same issue (myself, just now).

Answer (score 27):

`[Bb]in` will solve the problem, but... 
Here a more extensive list of things you should ignore (sample list by GitExtension):

```
#ignore thumbnails created by windows
Thumbs.db
#Ignore files build by Visual Studio
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.bak
*.cache
*.ilk
*.log
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug*/
*.sbr
obj/
[Rr]elease*/
_ReSharper*/
```

Comment: Note: Stuff like this should be in your GLOBAL gitignore (usually in your home directory.)  The project gitignore should only ignore things specific to your project (i.e. .o files for a C app.)

Answer (score 19):

If you're looking for a great global `.gitignore` file for any Visual Studio ( .NET ) solution - I recommend you to use this one: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

AFAIK it has the most comprehensive `.gitignore` for .NET projects.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 18):

Literally none of the answers actually worked for me; the only one that worked for me was (on Linux):

```
**/bin
(yes without the / in the end)

git version 2.18.0
```

Comment: Did that ignore all folders named `bin` in the sub-directories as well?

Answer (score 7):

for 2.13.3 and onwards,writing just bin in your .gitignore file should ignore the bin and all its subdirectories and files

> **bin**

Answer (score 5):

As a notice;

If you think about `.gitignore` does not work in a way (so added `foo/*` folder in it but `git status` still showing that folder content(s) as modified or something like this), then you can use this command;

`git checkout -- foo/*`

Answer (score 4):

Adding **/bin/ to the .gitignore file did the trick for me (Note: bin folder wasn't added to index).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @CB Bailey's answer:

I tried to remove multiple folders (in subfolders) named `et-cache` (caching folder from Wordpress [divi](/questions/tagged/divi) theme) from the index and from being tracked.

I added

```
et-cache/
```

to the `.gitignore` file. But

```
git rm -r --cached et-cache
```

resulted in an error:

> fatal: pathspec 'et-cache' did not match any files

So the solution was to use powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem et-cache -Recurse |% {git rm -r --cached $_.FullName}
```

This searches for all subfolders named et-cache. Each of the folders path (fullname) is then used to remove it from tracking in git.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern inside `.gitignore` ends with a slash `/`, it will only find a match with a directory.

In other words, `bin/` will match a directory `bin` and paths underneath it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link `bin`.

---

If the pattern *does not contain a slash*, like in `bin` Git treats it as a shell glob pattern (greedy). So best would be to use simple `/bin`.

`bin` would not be the best solution for this particular problem.

Comment: Did you mean 'begin with' a `/`?

Answer (score 0):

In my case encoding of gitignore file was problematic, check if it is UTF-8