# .gitignore does not understand my folder wildcard on windows

Tags: windows, git, msysgit, gitignore

I'm encountering a weird issue with `.gitignore` on Windows.

I want git to ignore all `.exe` files, except those in the `Dependencies` folder (and all subfolders).

So I have:

`.gitignore`:

```
*.exe
!/Dependencies/**/*.exe
```

This, unfortunately, does not work.

Meanwhile, this does:

```
*.exe
!/Dependencies/folder/subfolder/*.exe
```

So I'm wondering, am I messing something up, or is this some kind of bug?

I'm running msysgit on Windows (Windows 7 x64) version 1.6.5.1-preview20091022

Thanks in advance for any input :)

Comment: This is effectively the same issue/misunderstanding as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since [git 1.8.2 (March, 8th 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt#L85-L88), the `**` is now supported:

> The patterns in `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files **can have `**/`, as a pattern that matches 0 or more levels of subdirectory**.
>
> E.g. "`foo/**/bar`" matches "`bar`" in "`foo`" itself or in a subdirectory of "`foo`".

In your case, that means this line might now be supported:

```
!/Dependencies/**/*.exe
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Von for the follow up.

Comment: For posterity, jdigital had it right as well; it was an issue with the Windows impl of fnmatch, which has now been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a `.gitignore` file to the `Dependencies` folder with

> *.exe

inside. The obvious downside is that ignore the specifications are scattered among several files now.

Comment: Why was this answer accepted and upvoted?  The question was how to ignore `*.exe` files **except** for those inside `Dependencies/`.

Answer (score 2):

The [.gitignore documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) says:

> git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag

It's possible that fnmatch on your platform does not support ** in a path.

Comment: @jdigital This is what I suspected (feared, really) as well. If this is the case, then it could potentially wreck havoc in cross-platform repos :(