# Git: ignoring everything except directories

Tags: git, design-patterns, gitosis, gitignore

I have read this manual: 
http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

As I am working with gitosis, I rather use a .gitignore than explicit git commands.
Thus says the manual:

> Of course, not tracking files with git
>   is just a matter of not calling git
>   add on them. But it quickly becomes
>   annoying to have these untracked files
>   lying around; e.g. they make git add .
>   practically useless, and they keep
>   showing up in the output of git
>   status.
>
> You can tell git to ignore certain
>   files by creating a file called
>   .gitignore in the top level of your 
>   working directory

I basically want to ignore everything, except two directories, recursively. Let's say /mywebapp (that contains two subdirectories like stylesheets and javascripts) and /mydata are those two directories. Now, I've been already told git does not track directories, but just files. The !-mark excludes, so I assume this could work with directories too. I figured out that using * would ignore everything else. How would I write up my .gitignore file?

My question is not how to add these directories manually by explicit adding. My question is how this is done inside a gitignore file.

Thanks for your help, comments and feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the '`*`' is delegated to the [`fnmatch` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899875/git-add-not-working-with-png-files/2900049#2900049) which doesn't always works the same on all platform.

With my msysgit, I manage to ignore all subdirectories *content* except one with

```
*/
!mySubDir
```

So in your case:

```
*/
!mywebapp 
!mydata
```

To use '`*`' (instead of '`*/`') is a bit too much in this instance: it would ignore all files and directories...