# .gitignore not working: files that should be ignored still get committed

Tags: git

I'm trying to create a new git repository from existing folder. I've created a `.gitignore` file in the root of the folder. But if I say

```
git add *
git commit
git push
```

files that should be ignored still get committed to the remote repository. I'm on Windows.
Also I've bought a license for SmartGIT. It also seems to ignore `.gitignore`. I have to manually select which new files to commit.

Comment: What version of Git are you using? Also, you mention that you are using Windows, so pathname separators are always trouble. Could you post an example of your `.gitignore` file that doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the content of your `.gitignore` file? `.gitignore` will use the underlying OS-specific  `fnname()` method: see for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330471 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572

Comment: I haven't heard of SmartGIT - I use MSysGit and TortoiseGit and they seem to work with .gitignore files well. If the issue is with SmartGIT then I would try the alternative of MSysGit and TortoiseGit.

Comment: Do publish the result of `git status` and the content of `.gitignore`.
On msysgit, directory separator are forward slashes: `/`, how does it look like for you?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767147/how-do-i-tell-git-to-ignore-gitignore), which covers this ground in more detail...

Answer (score 31):

Your file must still be tracked, you can see by doing `git status` that will show you that your file is modified even if it's in .gitignore
You need to do this:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [path_to_file]
```

Comment: That should be the accepted answer, so after adding file(s) in .gitignore it still shows up in git status. After above command, I got the desired result

Answer (score 27):

Try "`git add .`" instead.

Also, it works for me (on Linux):

```
$ git init
$ echo foo > .gitignore
$ echo foo > foo
$ echo bar > bar
$ git add -v *
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
foo
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

Answer (score 25):

Are your files already tracked?  .gitignore only silences comments about untracked files, but won't stop a tracked file from being tracked.

Answer (score 12):

I've had issues with .gitignore also. I checked out the linked answers listed about, which fixed half the issue.

What really got gitignore working full for me was adding a comment on  the first line of the file. Git wasn't parsing the exclude situated on the first line.

Cheers

Comment: Adding the comment on windows worked for me as well. +1 for you!

Comment: Sadly I figured this out for myself first...  then found your comment.  Now on to seeing if this is a bug that ought to be fixed!

Answer (score 6):

You could have created a UTF-8 encoded text file. Try saving it as ANSI encoded. In git bash, you can verify by using vi -b.

Comment: Seems to be the cause. I didn't use `vi -b` but it worked after rewriting .gitignore from scratch

Answer (score 4):

A trick I faced on windows is that using `echo` (as per Jakub Narębski answer) you have to be careful with spaces.

As you can see below any space before the redirection operator does have an effect on the actual ignore.

```
C:\test>dir /B
TOBEIGNORED

C:\test>echo TOBEIGNORED > .gitignore
C:\test>git status
[...]
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .gitignore
#       TOBEIGNORED
C:\test>echo TOBEIGNORED> .gitignore
C:\test>git status
[...]
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .gitignore
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: YES DONT USE ECHO ON WINDOWS OR YOU WILL WASTE 3 HOURS FIGURING OUT WHY THE HELL THE .gitignore JUST DOES NOT WORK

Answer (score 0):

Probably your exclude file mask is inacurate.

Comment: I've copied .gitignore file from another project, where it works.

Comment: Is .gitignore accessible to git user? Maybe it's a permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using git version 1.7.12.3 on MacOSX and the first line of .gitignore is also not taken into account. Just add a comment as first line.

Answer (score 0):

Comment line as the first line of the file is critical!  I spent considerable time trying to exclude files only to find that GIT was ignoring the first line in the ignore file.

Comment: This is definitively not the issue. Almost none of my gitignore files (~50) has a comment in the first line, and they all work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I lastly did `echo node_modules >> .gitignore`, and it wasn't working.

The windows terminal saves the file in `UCS-2 LE BOM` and git doesn't accept that.

It latter worked when I opened the file with `Notepad` and saved it with `UTF-8` encoding

[image: notepad save utf-8 encoding]

**It Worked fine then.**

I think they need to fix this since `echo "filetoignore" >> .gitignore` actually seems a handy thing to do