# git ignore exception not working as desired

Tags: git, windows-xp, gitignore

WinXP + mysisGit1.7

In my .gitignore file, but still can't see `Demos/path/to/file/file.cpp` being tracked by git.

I have below entries:

```
Demos/
!Demos/path/to/file/file.cpp
```

The absolute path is: `c:\Project\Demos\path\to\file\file.cpp`

What could be wrong? Please help, thanks.

**EDIT:**

I found the way how mysisGit .gitignore work on WindowsXP can only ignore certain type of file, then exclude some files with same type. For example:

```
*.bak
!tracking.bak
!/path/to/file/tracking2.bak
```

It doesn't work ignore folder and exclude some files under that folder. Below won't work:

```
/folderUnderRepoRoot/
!/folderUnderRepoRoot/tracking.cpp
```

Nor

```
anyFolderNamedLikeThis/
!anyFolderNamedLikeThis/tracking.cpp
!/anyFolderNamedLikeThis/tracking.cpp
```

However, I do find that there's an exception. There's a work-around way to exclude files just right under the ignored folder (not to its subfolder). **This works.**

```
/folderUnderRepoRoot/*
/folderUnderRepoRoot/tracking.cpp
```

But this way is only limited when the file is not in any subfolder, so it's not so useful.

So I end up still commit most of source files, even I was only interested in a few files while tracking some others big project. Which means there're a bunch of files I won't touch but still need to commit them.

Here is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330471/gitignore-does-not-understand-my-folder-wildcard-on-windows) that had similar problem.

Comment: Did you `git add Demos/path/to/file/file.cpp` to start tracking it?

Comment: @Stan: did you find a solution ? I found the same problem on git and ubuntu so it's not platform related

Comment: has my answer been helpful?

Answer (score 30):

Your `.gitignore` exception does not work because "It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded" ([source](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)). This is "a performance related quirk in Git" ([source](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore)).

As an ugly-but-functional workaround, do this for every directory in the path to your file:

1. Exclude the contents of the directory.
2. Re-include the sub-directory leading to your file (resp. finally, re-include your file).

Your entries would look like this, with each two-line section corresponding to the two steps above for one directory level:

```
Demos/*
!Demos/path/

Demos/path/*
!Demos/path/to/

Demos/path/to/*
!Demos/path/to/file/

Demos/path/to/file/*
!Demos/path/to/file/file.cpp
```

**Notes:**

The first line is not `Demos/`, unlike what the question author tried. `Demos` is a parent directory of our file, so we would have to re-include it right afterwards – means, we do not have to exclude it in the first place. Instead, we start by excluding only its *contents*: `Demos/*`.

Comment: I like this answer, but I needed just a single-asterisk `Demos/*` , `Demos/path/*`, instead of two asterisks, `**`. From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore): 
`Example to exclude everything except a specific directory foo/bar`

Comment: @TheRedPea You're right! I have adapted my answer. A trailing `/**` is only different when re-including (`!…` lines). When excluding, it's just the same as `/*`.

Answer (score 3):

Do add to `.gitignore` as follows:

```
folderUnderRepoRoot/**/*
!folderUnderRepoRoot/tracking.cpp
```

But make sure, that at least a one file added to git index from the `folderUnderRepoRoot` folder.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just one file, I wouldn't normally modify `.gitignore`

The following should ignore `.gitignore` and allow you to add the file

```
git add -f Demos/path/to/file/file.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing it with `!/Demos/path/to/file/file.cpp` (note the leading slash after the exclamation mark) instead and try again?

Answer (score 0):

for me, the case was so much different. I tried to ignore all files starting with "secrets" except this file "secrets.[stage].json" as it is just a template for developers.
This doesn't work

---

secrets*

!secrets.[stage].json

---

I found out that it was just because bracket is a special character that need to be escaped so this was the solution

---

secrets*

!secrets.[stage].json

---

The same problem happens with other special characters.

As .gitignore uses globbing patterns to match against file names.
You can find the documentation of globbing patterns here
https://linux.die.net/man/7/glob
Which was much better for me than the official .gitignore documentation.