# git ignore directory except for specified

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore entire public_html/ directory except one file inside

I give .gitignore as below:

```
public_html/*
!public_html/config/config.php
```

However, when I run git status , I can not find config.php has been included.

Comment: Similar to this post? Seems to be a problem on windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667986/git-ignore-exception-not-working-as-desired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First commit / add `public_html/config/config.php` and then add `public_html` to the gitignore.

Answer (score 10):

Change .gitignore to

```
public_html/*
```

And force adding config.php into index.

```
git add -f public_html/config/config.php
```