# git ignore exception not working multiple subdirectories below ignored directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I am having an issue where the exception syntax for gitignore (!fileName.txt) is not working when the file is multiple subdirectories below the ignored directory.

For instance:

```
web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/*
!web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/[Ss]hell/[Tt]hemes/[Ss]tandard/[Cc]ustom/32x32*
```

does not include the files in the folder 32x32.
I have to manually add them via command line like so:

```
git add -f -r web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/[Ss]hell/[Tt]hemes/[Ss]tandard/[Cc]ustom/32x32
```

Is there a way to use the exception operator in a situation like this?

Comment: And what does **[`git check-ignore`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18953923/6309)** says? What actual ignore rule is applied or not applied?

Comment: I tried doing git check-ignore in the bash and it says command not found.

Comment: It is a fairly recent command. What git version are you using?

Comment: so I just updated git and when I use that command I don't get any output at all. I used a command similar to this: git check-ignore web/Example.Web/sitecore/shell

Comment: And with `git check-ignore -v -n web/Example.Web/sitecore/shell`?

Comment: Also can you try an ignore rule like `web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/**` instead of `web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/*`?

Comment: This is what I got from running the git check-ignore command ::      web/Example.Web/sitecore/shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-including a file that "is multiple subdirectories below the ignored directory" (as you try), does not work because "It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded" [[source](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)].

As an ugly-but-working workaround, re-include all parent directories along the path before re-including your desired file, while keeping the files in these parent directories out by re-excluding them.

For your example it would like as follows:

```
web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/*

!web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/[Ss]hell/
web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/[Ss]hell/**
!web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/[Ss]hell/[Tt]hemes/
web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/[Ss]hell/[Tt]hemes/**
!web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/[Ss]hell/[Tt]hemes/[Ss]tandard/
web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/[Ss]hell/[Tt]hemes/[Ss]tandard/**
!web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/[Ss]hell/[Tt]hemes/[Ss]tandard/[Cc]ustom/
web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/[Ss]hell/[Tt]hemes/[Ss]tandard/[Cc]ustom/**
!web/[Ee]xample.[Ww]eb/[Ss]itecore/[Ss]hell/[Tt]hemes/[Ss]tandard/[Cc]ustom/32x32*
```

Source: my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25475163/1270008).

**Alternatively,** you could instead use .gitignore files that are placed in the directory of files to re-include [[more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16679292/1270008)]. Depending on taste, this could be the prettier solution.