# Capistrano uploads the .git directory

Tags: php, git, version-control, deployment, capistrano

I am using git with capistrano.

I initialized my project inside my folder on my local machine as such:

```
git init
```

I then pushed the project the server directory
I then called `cap deploy`
The deploy works, except that it uploads the local .git folder structure, as well as my .gitignore and Capfile to a publicly accessible folder.

Here's my gitignore file:

```
.DS_Store
uploads/**/*
Capfile
.gitignore
.git/**/*
```

This doesn't seem to do the trick. Any help?

Thanks!

---

Edit: updated .gitignore file:

Changed deployment strategy to export:

```
set :deploy_via, :export
```

This works for ignoring the .git folder, but the contents of my .gitignore file seen below are still not taken into account

```
.DS_Store
includes/php/config.php
/uploads
Capfile
.git
```

---

---

---

---

---

**EDIT 2 (Solution):** Edit 1 in combination with the following did the trick.
Files that were already added prior to being listed in the .gitignore file would constantly be uploaded. Say I had the following .gitignore file.

```
.DS_Store
includes/php/config.php
```

Then I ran the following commands:

```
git add .
git commit -a -m 'some commit'
```

Then I decided to add to my .gitignore file so it now looks like this:

```
.DS_Store
includes/php/config.php
Capfile
```

Then again, I ran:

```
git add .
git commit -a -m 'another commit'
```

Now I'd see that `.DS_Store` and `includes/php/config.php` have not been uploaded, but that the Capfile has... This is what happened to me in my original question.
The reason: I think the .gitignore file is taken into account only when adding (i.e. `git add .`). If I already added files, then put them in the .gitignore file, they would have already been added to the project. I'd need to use the `git rm` command to remove them.
I just started anew with a new .git repo and that solved the problem, but you don't have to - you can just remove whatever files you already added but now want to ignore with the `git rm` command.

I selected the answer that helped me get to this conclusion as the right one, though the complete solution was just detailed above.

Comment: Is `git` ignoring the files you want `git` to ignore?

Comment: it is ignoring one config file i want it to ignore, but not whole folders - am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What is your deploy strategy?

Do you have Capistrano setup to exclude the .git file?
if you are using `set :deploy_via, :copy` then make sure to add the following:

`set :copy_exclude, [".git/*", ".svn/*", ".DS_Store"]`

Otherwise use `set :deploy_via, :export` which should ignore your source control folders

http://www.capify.org/index.php/Understanding_Deployment_Strategies

Comment: that worked for ignoring the .git folder, but my .gitignore file is still not taken into account. Please see edit

Comment: do you have `set :scm, :git` in your deploy?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory/1470664#1470664), it appears you don't need the wild card selectors and can just have:

```
uploads/
```

You need to deploy via `:git` in Capistrano and do an export. It's essentially a `git clone` and then just deletes the `.git` directory afterwards.

Your problem isn't much to do with Cap really. Make sure your `.gitignore` file is working correctly.