# git untracked files - how to ignore

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs, gitignore, git-status

When I run `git status`, I see the "Untracked files" section has many files (some with a "." extension.)

I don't think I have to do anything, but it doesnt look good to see these files whenever I run `git status`. Is there any way to not to see these files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.gitignore - ignore any 'bin' directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory)

Comment: More likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542687/git-how-to-ignore-all-present-untracked-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: How to ignore all present untracked files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542687/git-how-to-ignore-all-present-untracked-files)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to create one or several `.gitignore` files. They can be stored in git itself, or just kept local.

Comment: sorry, how do i do this? I don't have access to the main git account.

Comment: @Jay Just do it. You don't have to have access to the "main git account", whatever that is. Just create a file called ".gitignore" and start putting things in it.

Answer (score 21):

Files that are "yours", files that no one else sees, write in .git/info/exclude.

For files that everyone else sees, write them down in .gitignore at the project top directory and then add and commit the .gitignore file.

For example, your .gitignore might look like so:

```
*.o
.*.sw[op]
*~
```

Comment: What do you mean by "files that no one else sees"?

Comment: Files that are local to your setup; for instance you may have a utility script in your working tree that is not tracked by git and only you can see.

Answer (score 14):

You can make git ignore all files that match a regular expression (like all files *.ext) by adding the line `*.ext` in file `.git/info/exclude`.

Added Abe Voelker's comment bellow to improve the answer:

Note that this approach is local to your repository. If you ever clone it (e.g. share it with others), your ignore settings will not be pulled in.

If you need to share the ignore settings, you should put it in `.gitignore` files

Comment: gitignore lines are not regular expressions, but rather more like shell globs.

Answer (score 10):

To ignore, use `.gitignore`, as Sam Hocevar said.

To delete, you'll probably want to do a `git clean`, which will clean up any files that aren't tracked by git. You might need to use the `-f` and `-d` switches if you've got directories which aren't tracked.

Be careful with `git clean`, it will delete things you haven't added to git yet!

Comment: beware, git clean will remove the files from hdd! but its working. :)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do this globally all the time do

```
git config status.showuntrackedfiles no
```

Comment: This will only change for the current repository. If you want to do this globally as for all the repository on your machine for this user, use --global after config. For all user, use --system.