# git: How to ignore all present untracked files?

Tags: git, gitignore

Is there a handy way to ignore all untracked files and folders in a git repository?
(I know about the `.gitignore`.)

So `git status` would provide a clean result again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a way to get git not to show the untracked files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774416/is-there-a-way-to-get-git-not-to-show-the-untracked-files)

Comment: Or you may want to add a single * to your .gitignore file. :)

Comment: Just a `*` will very likely not be what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add all currently untracked files/folders to git ignore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862598/how-to-add-all-currently-untracked-files-folders-to-git-ignore)

Comment: Surprised at so many incorrect answers. `-u no` is wrong. `-uno` is correct. `-u no` tries to do a status on a file called `no`! The `no` is *not* an argument to `-u`. To force `no` to be interpreted as an argument to `-u`, there must be no space. To test this, do `touch Invalid` and compare `git status -uInvalid` to `git status -u Invalid`.

Comment: Since the `no` of `-uno` is supposed to be an argument to `-u`, it's reasonable to consider git's option parsing to be broken.  Historically, options that take arguments usually allow spaces between them.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

As already been said, to exclude from status just use:

```
git status -uno  # must be "-uno" , not "-u no"
```

If you instead want to permanently ignore currently untracked files you can, from the root of your project, launch:

```
git status --porcelain | grep '^??' | cut -c4- >> .gitignore
```

Every subsequent call to `git status` will explicitly ignore those files.

**UPDATE**: the above command has a minor drawback: if you don't have a `.gitignore` file yet your gitignore will ignore itself! This happens because the file `.gitignore` gets created before the `git status --porcelain` is executed. So if you don't have a `.gitignore` file yet I recommend using:

```
echo "$(git status --porcelain | grep '^??' | cut -c4-)" > .gitignore
```

This creates a subshell which completes *before* the `.gitignore` file is created.

**COMMAND EXPLANATION** I'll explain the command:

- `git status --porcelain` is used instead of `git status --short` because [manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html) states "Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts. This is similar to the short output, but will remain stable across git versions and regardless of user configuration." So we have both the parseability and stability;
- `grep '^??'` filters only the lines starting with `??`, which, according to the [git status manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html), correspond to the untracked files;
- `cut -c4-` removes the first 3 characters of every line, which gives us just the relative path to the untracked file;
- the `|` symbols are [pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29#Piping), which pass the output of the previous command to the input of the following command;
- the `>>` and `>` symbols are [redirect operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29#Variants), which append the output of the previous command to a file or overwrites/creates a new file, respectively.

**ANOTHER VARIANT** for those who prefer [using `sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24151/49405) instead of `grep` and `cut`, here's another way:

```
git status --porcelain | sed -n -e 's/^?? //p' >> .gitignore
```

Comment: `cut -c4- ` **removes the first 4 characters of every line, which gives us just the relative path to the untracked file;** No. `-c` marks the beginning of a list of column numbers to cut. And  `4-` *selects* the line from column 4 to the end, which cuts columns 1-3.  So your cut command actually removes the first 3 characters of each line. If you removed 4 characters from a git status line such as the one for this file here: `?? app/views/static_pages/contact.html.erb`, you would remove the first letter of `app`.  So the command is correct, but the explanation is faulty.

Comment: @7stud: thank you, you are right, I've wrote 4 by mistake. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Slight correction for my comment above: *-c marks the beginning of a list of columns to select*.  Any column not selected is cut.

Comment: I really appreciate the command explanation. Its nice to know what the random commands I copied from the internet are doing, and helps us all learn how to use the command line and git better.

Comment: `-u no` doesn't work for me. But `-uno` does. I've updated the answer accordingly. This is strange design for git. I'm on git 1.7.1

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: thanks. The change is documented [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg260063.html), and discussed [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg259971.html)

Comment: Many times when I have output from a command I want to send to a file but I don't want the presence of the file included, I pipe the output through `sort -o filename`.  Obviously sometimes that's going to corrupt the output if order is important.

Comment: This solution is slightly incorrect.  The files listed miss a leading `/`, so there should be a step inserted that prepends `/` to every file.

Comment: @AndreasAbel this should work:
`git status --porcelain | sed -n -e 's,^?? ,/,p' >> .gitignore`

Answer (score 65):

If you want to permanently ignore these files, a simple way to add them to `.gitignore` is:

1. Change to the root of the git tree.
2. `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard >> .gitignore`

This will enumerate all files inside untracked directories, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Why doesn't this get as many votes?  No need to pipe through 2 other programs!

Comment: @JoelFan: two reasons:
1) **this one works only from the root of the git**, while the accepted one works from every subdirectory, you just need to tweak the destination `.gitignore` path
2) if you have an untracked directory, **this one list each and every single file in it, but not the untracked directory itself** (so you won't ignore the directory, and thus still get reported future files in the directory as untracked, while the accepted one lists only the directory, and not the untracked files inside. This is a matter of what you want to do, but often you just want to ignore the whole dir

Comment: Thank you Poolie I appreciate the difference *of* your suggestion *because* of the points mentioned by @Diego I started working with a library of files & folders and I don't want to track/push the original files. I only want to track files I add or rebuild in the library. Adding the parent folders would ignore everything. This/your solution added all 1696 files in a snap. xD

Comment: This can also be achieved using `git config status.showUntrackedFiles no`.

Comment: @Diego, it's inaccurate that it only works in the root git directory. It works in any subdirectory but it adds to that subdirectories `.gitignore`, which is valid in many use-cases

Comment: This is the more elegant solution, which works for many common cases.  Minor flaw in the ointment: The files listed miss a leading `/`, so there should be a step inserted that prepends `/` to every file.

Answer (score 25):

Found it in [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status)

> The mode parameter is used to specify the handling of untracked files. It is optional: it defaults to all, and if specified, it must be stuck to the option (e.g. -uno, but not -u no).

`git status -uno`

Comment: Well if everyone would RTFM before posting, none of us would ever get any rep :-)

Answer (score 13):

IMHO better than the accepted answer is to use the following:

`git config --local status.showUntrackedFiles no`

The accepted answer does not work for when new files are added that are not in `.gitignore`

Comment: The question title mentions "present untracked files", so there's no mention of ignoring future files. Also ignoring all future untracked files is quite a rare use case, I would say.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for! (Even though it doesn't seem to be what the OP here was looking for...) @Diego, anyone searching StackOverflow for things like this already likely has a rare usecase lol.

Answer (score 10):

None of the above answers worked for me.

In my case, I want a personal config file to be ignored permanently (`git status -uno` only works for one use).

I'm part of a team so can't add it to `.gitignore` as that's checked in.

Mu solution was to add it to:

```
.git/info/exclude
```

which is like your own personal `.gitignore` file.

Comment: exactly what I needed! thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Two ways:

- use the argument `-uno` to `git-status`. Here's an example:

  ```
  [jenny@jenny_vmware:ft]$ git status
  # On branch ft
  # Untracked files:
  #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
  #
  #       foo
  nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
  [jenny@jenny_vmware:ft]$ git status -uno
  # On branch ft
  nothing to commit (working directory clean)
  ```
- Or you can add the files and directories to `.gitignore`, in which case they will never show up.

Comment: A handy way of editing the `.gitignore` being `git status | cat >> temp && vim temp`. Then editing the file so the first few lines and last line is deleted, as well as trailing `#` and the whitespace after it. Then `cat temp >> .gitignore && rm temp`. In case no `.gitignore` was present before, `mv temp .gitignore` will do. Ugly stuff but better than updating the `.gitignore` manually.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The correct answer is `-uno`. If you use `-u no`, it is equivalent to `no -u` - it will do a status on a file called `no` (which probably doesn't exist) and use the default `-u` mode. i.e. it is equivalent to `git status no`

Answer (score 5):

`-u no` doesn't show unstaged files either.  `-uno` works as desired and shows unstaged, but hides untracked.

Comment: Even this isn't quite correct.  `git status -u X` is equivalent to `git status X -u` (`X` is not an argument to `-u`). This, in turn, is equivalent to `git status X` (because `-u` without an argument is the default `-u`). Therefore, it is simply a git-status on file `X`. So, if `X` is `no` it simply tries to do a git status on a file called `no`, which you probably don't have

Answer (score 2):

In case **you are not on Unix like** OS, this would work on **Windows** using **PowerShell**

`git status --porcelain | ?{ $_ -match "^\?\? " }| %{$_ -replace "^\?\? ",""} | Add-Content .\.gitignore`

However, `.gitignore` file has to have a new empty line, otherwise it will append text to the last line no matter if it has content.

This might be a better alternative:

`$gi=gc .\.gitignore;$res=git status --porcelain|?{ $_ -match "^\?\? " }|%{ $_ -replace "^\?\? ", "" }; $res=$gi+$res; $res | Out-File .\.gitignore`

Comment: What does this do?

Answer (score 2):

```
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -fxd
```

will remove any untracked files, and make your local branch up to date with the remote branch. this is good option if you don't want to preserve any local changes you already made.

Comment: Be careful with the first command. This will remove all your local changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have *a lot of* untracked files, and don't want to "`gitignore`" all of them, note that, since [git 1.8.3 (April, 22d 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt#L103-L104), `git status` will mention the `--untracked-files=no` even if you didn't add that option in the first place!

> "`git status`" suggests users to look into using `--untracked=no` option when it takes too long.

Answer (score 0):

I came here trying to solve a slightly different problem.  Maybe this will be useful to someone else:

I create a new branch `feature-a`.  as part of this branch I create new directories and need to modify .gitignore to suppress some of them.  This happens a lot when adding new tools to a project that create various cache folders.  `.serverless`, `.terraform`, etc.

Before I'm ready to merge that back to master I have something else come up, so I checkout `master` again, but now `git status` picks up those suppressed folders again, since the .gitignore hasn't been merged yet.

The answer here is actually simple, though I had to find [this blog](https://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2009/02/25/git-tip-how-to-merge-specific-files-from-another-branch/) to figure it out:

Just checkout the .gitignore file from `feature-a` branch

```
git checkout feature-a -- feature-a/.gitignore
git add .
git commit -m "update .gitignore from feature-a branch"
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Diego's answer above, I think the mentioned solutions will fail for files with spaces (and possibly other special characters, like " itself, although I haven't checked) in their names. This line:

```
echo "$(git status --porcelain | grep '^??' | cut -c4- | sed 's/^\"//;s/\"$//')" >> .gitignore
```

removes starting and trailing double quotes where present which fixes it.

I'm not very good with sed though, there may be a better way to do this, or edge cases.