# how to add all currently untracked files/folders to git ignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I initialized the `git` repository and made a first commit.
Now, in this directory I run `./configure` and `./make all` so that it populates a lot of extra files/folders don't want to track.

What I would like to do, is to add all those untracked files once and for all to my gitignore. Is there any simple way to do it?

I can get rid of some unnecessary files like `*.o` or `*.mod` by specifying appropriate lines in .gitignore, but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: How to ignore all present untracked files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542687/git-how-to-ignore-all-present-untracked-files)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this:

```
git status -s | grep -e "^\?\?" | cut -c 4- >> .gitignore
```

Explanation: `git status -s` gives you a short version of the status, without headers. The `grep` takes only lines that start with `??`, i.e. untracked files, the `cut` removes the `??`, and the rest adds it to the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: The command will also ignore your `.gitignore` file. If you want to track your .gitignore file, use the command `git status -s | grep -e "^\?\?" | grep -v ".gitignore" | cut -c 4- >> .gitignore`

Comment: Windows solution please!

Comment: @calbertts in cmd, `findstr /C:"text"` is basically the equivalent of `grep "text"`

Comment: This command also list my `modified` files

Comment: Fab solution, worked out of the box on windows using [cgwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html), thanks!

Answer (score 12):

A simpler command to do this is

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard >> .gitignore
```

You might want to edit the result to replace repeated patterns with wildcards.

Comment: I'm not sure about this answer because it adds the full path up to the file name. To me the accepted answer is better because it add only the first level deep i.e. dir1/ instead of dir1/dir2/dirn/file1, dir1/file, etc

Answer (score 1):

If your working tree is clean except for the untracked files/folders, a shorter solution is possible using `awk`:

```
git status -s | awk '{print $2}' >> .gitignore
```

Answer (score 0):

in the accepted answer, the grep part was causing me problem (i.e. was not filtering, instead all lines including those starting with `M` (modified) were shown as well), and replacing `"^\?\?"` with `"^??"` solved it for me. I am on win 10 and using it in msys2's bash.

Answer (score 0):

This works too when there are spaces in the untracked stuff
and is shorter:

```sh
git status -s | grep -oP '^\?\? "?\K[^"]+' >>.gitignore
```