# Git - ignore extension in a specific folder

Tags: git, gitignore

What is the right syntax of .gitignore to exclude all the `*.cache` files in all subdirectories of `/StringsEditor` directory?

I tried both `/StringsEditor/*.cache` and `/StringsEditor/*/*.cache` but none of them works.

Comment: did you try `/StringsEditor/**.cache`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `*.cache` in `StringsEditor/.gitignore`.

Comment: Let me mark your reply as the cleverest one. I have nearly forgotten that .gitignore could be in every folder.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably the result of a misunderstanding. Paths in .gitignore do not need to be relative to the root of the repository. I.e. you could ignore just `*.cache`. If you actually do only want this to occur for StringsEditor subdirectories, then you can use `StringsEditor/**/*.cache`.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory).

Comment: The true reason was that I should also remove corresponding files from git to make them untracked.