# Ignoring specific directory names in git

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory structure which has a lot of `result` directories that are generated automatically.

How can I set git to ignore those `result` directories? The issue might be there is no specific rule how the `result` directory is generated.

Comment: Have you tried adding `result/`?

Comment: Wait, so the directory name isn’t actually `result`, but instead could be any arbitrary name whose naming scheme you cannot specify?

Comment: Here is same issue for bin folder, you change it for result
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An entry like

```
result/
```

in a `.gitignore` file at the repository root should suffice. If your directories are all named dynamically, then consider moving them under one directory, whose name you know - or move generated code completely outside the repo.

Comment: Add it to where? ;-)  It might be helpful to state that in your response.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a file named `.gitignore` and add the files (or directories) you want git to ignore to it.

but for the gitignore to work, you must add + commit it to your repo.

more info on the file structure here: http://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitignore.html