# Using .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I am having trouble with my .gitignore. I have a directory tree like so:

```
/djangoproject
    venv
        bin
            startgunicorn.sh
        djo
    www
        static
        analytics
    .git
        .gitignore
```

My .gitignore reads:

```
../www/analytics
../venv/bin
../venv/build
../venv/include
../venv/lib
../venv/local
*.pyc
```

When I

`git add ../*` or `git add -A`

`git push`

I don't want `startgunicorn.sh` or my `analytics` dir to be pushed, but I do want `djo` and `static` to be. That's not happening—my gunicorn.sh file keeps changing to the local machine's. Where is my error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never seen anyone place a `.gitignore` file in the `.git` subdirectory before. As far as I know, it should be in the root if you wish to apply the rules to the entire repository.

[GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) say the following:

> Note that you can create a .gitignore in any subpath to have its rules
>   applied at that path. Sometimes an empty .gitignore file is used as a
>   placeholder for an empty path, for example to force git to generate a
>   log/ path for your development environment to use.

Going by that logic, all those rules will all be applied from the .git folder downwards. I can see what you're trying to do, but I've never seen it done before that way.

I would put the .gitignore in the root of the repository, and have it look like this:

```
www/analytics
venv/bin
venv/build
venv/include
venv/lib
venv/local
*.pyc
```

I'd expect that to do the right thing.

In addition, it is worth bearing this in mind:

> Note that git will not ignore a file that was already tracked before a
>   rule was added to this file to ignore it. In such a case the file must
>   be un-tracked, usually with git rm --cached filename

You will possibly need to do that, if you've added older versions of those files you wish to ignore.

Comment: Late to the party but for those following along at home, starting with git 1.8.2, `**` can be used to ignore all files in a folder up to infinite depth. E.g., `venv/**`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try placing .gitignore in main project's directory (where .git directory is) and removing "../" at beginings of paths.

If that doesn't help try adding

```
venv/bin/*
```

to your .gitignore.