# Recursively ignore folder in git

Tags: git

How to ignore all folders with name `build`, `bin`. I tried doing this

```
**/bin/
**/build/
```

but it doesn't work. in git status i see

```
#   new file:   BS/server/build/obj/sender.o
#   new file:   BS/server/build/obj/sendistate.o
#   new file:   BS/server/build/obj/serializedata.o
#   new file:   BS/client/bin/gc.sample.xml
#   new file:   BS/client/bin/mkab.qss
#   new file:   BS/client/bin/mkaberr.qss
#   new file:   BS/client/build/debug/application.qss
#   new file:   BS/client/build/debug/config.xml
```

Comment: `*/build/*` should be better

Comment: possible duplicate of [.gitignore - ignore any 'bin' directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory)

Comment: Rémi Benoit it doesn't work. I can do */*/buid/*, but i need do this recursive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to ignore directory, you should be "directoryname/".
For example

```
bin/
build/
```