# TortoiseGit unversion entire folder

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I created a new folder (myApp) locally and copied some files/folders from another reference directory/folder (which was taken from a Git repo using TortoiseGit)

Now this new folder (myApp) is also showing the tracking things or icons like green tick, cross mark, etc
I want this to be removed completely (folder/sub-folders, files, etc)
i.e. I just want to keep the folder locally myApp without any kind of tracking.

How can I do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory

Answer (score 2):

Hold the Shift-Key and open the context menu on that folder. Then select "Delete (keep local)". This unversiones the selected folder/files. Then commit these changes so that the files are removed in the repository.

If you then want that this folder/file does not appear on the commit dialog, you have to add it to the ignore list.

Comment: Thx...I just did that...But it is now showing a red cross next to the files/folders...I just wnt it as a normal folder (nothing to do with Git)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that you have to commit in order to remove the files from the repository (those file are still included in the HEAD revision).

Comment: But I do not want anything to be comitted to the remote repo. So not sure if this action will prevent that from happening?

Comment: When you just copied other files into your repository and did not add them, those files are NOT versioned.

Comment: Please add a screenshot to your question.