# Unity Google Play Services version replace every time after git pull

Tags: github, replace, google-play-services, unity-game-engine

We are using Unity on a github repository and everytime two of us push and pull changes, Unity asks us the following, every time:

> Unity remove or replace play-services-plus version 8.3.0 with version
>   8.4.0

This results in a constant push of deleted 8.3 files and add of 8.4 files.

I'm not very familiar with either the play services or gitignoring things and would like to know what causes the continuous reimport and how to make it a constant change

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much what you want.
[.gitignore - ignore any 'bin' directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory)

Edit your git.ignore to include the directory of play services folder.

As for the issue itself, I'd imagine one of you has a local reference to some play services scripts that are changing the project settings. Either way, it's not something you really need to track so you can just go ahead and ignore it.

Comment: Hey Liam,

thanks for the late reply. We fixed it, we just oversaw that our play services version on the machines differed. Everything is fine now.