# gitignore file not work after push?

Tags: git, github

How to add `.gitignore` file after already push my project? I'm a git starter. Recently I pushed my Intellij Project to github, then I want to add `.gitignore` file to shrink my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create .gitignore file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744305/how-to-create-gitignore-file)

Comment: @IvanLeonenko  i kow how to create `.gitignore` file . i just want to know could i add my `.gitignore` file after i already push my project to remote repo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot ignore a file once its been committed. You need to use `git rm` to remove the files from the repo and then re-commit with them added to the git ignore file.

Eg. I could remove all .htaccess files like:

```
git rm -r .htaccess
```

[Also see Git Ignore docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: So I can `git rm -r .` and then repush my project?

Comment: Yes exactly, just don't forgot to do the .gitignore file first. Also you could add --cached to rm to leave a cached version there in the history. Good luck!