# Gitignore not ignoring folders

Tags: git

I have added multiple folders to my `.gitignore` files, but they still appear when I do `git status`.

My installation/computer is new, and I'm trying to init a git repository inside a svn one.

As I've done hundreds of times before (not on this machine though), the folders marked as ignored (notably the `.svn` folder at the root, and `bin` and `obj` inside `src/www`) should not appear when doing `git status`, and they should not be added when doing `git add .`, but they do.

> D:\DEV> more .gitignore
>   .svn/
>   [Bb]in/
>   [Oo]bj/
>   packages/
>
> D:\DEV> git status
>   On branch master
>   Untracked files:
>   (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
>
> ```
>     .svn/  
>     src/UI.Admin.Tests/obj/  
>     src/packages/  
>     src/www/bin/  
>     src/www/obj/
> ```
>
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to
>   track)

Comment: Have these folders already been versioned by Git (i.e. were they previously committed to the repository)?  If so, then adding them to `.gitignore` won't work.  You will have to `git -rm` them first.

Comment: No, I have not ever added these folders.

Comment: The folders are showing up as being untracked, which means they will not be committed if you were to do a `git commit`. So there is nothing to worry about.  If someone else commits these folders and you pull, your Git will ignore anything coming from the repository.

Comment: Yes but they are added if I do a `git add .`. They should not appear at all when doing `git status`

Comment: I don't see those `src` files listed in your `.gitignore`.

Comment: @AD7six : you're right, I've replaced the screenshot with some text, and added more explanation as to what I'm expecting.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : yes, it's the `.svn/` folder at the root that should be ignored, as well as the `bin` and `obj` folders inside `src/www`.

Comment: You never ignored `src`... I don't see `src` anywhere in your `.gitignore` file, unless I am an ignoramus.

Comment: I don't want to ignore `src/`, I want to ignore the `bin` and `obj` folders inside. It should be easy : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1470582/6776 ; additionnaly, you can see that I ignored the `.svn` folder but it still appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer (but I'm not sure what's the source of the problem).

I have deleted the `.gitignore` file and recreated it using `touch .gitignore`.

I had copy/pasted the original file content from some website, I'm assuming it has something to do with the encoding or something like this.