# Xcode .gitIgnore showing shows files with ignored folder

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore

I have tried to solve this by

1. **Deleting** all pods and re installing
2. **Cleaning** build folder
3. **Deleting** .gitignore and recreating

However there are a few files within the Pods dir that continue to show up

I'm ignoring using this in my .gitignore since my initial commit - nothing in this has ever been committed.

```
Pods/
```

Note this has only started recently with a with a new pod update

When I try to commit I get the following.

All other pods within this dir are ignored.

I have looked at these, but no luck fixing

[.gitignore ignoring whitelisted folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003448/gitignore-ignoring-whitelisted-folder)

[.gitignore not ignoring folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39014896/gitignore-not-ignoring-folder)

[Gitignore not ignoring folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227797/gitignore-not-ignoring-folders)

[.gitignore doesn't ignore files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965060/gitignore-doesnt-ignore-files)

This looked like it may have the solution but not sure if I want to try it, so decided to post and understand the reason why this is happening

[gitignore does not ignore folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410208/gitignore-does-not-ignore-folder)

Note: Running Swift 4.2 / Xcode 10.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You were tracking this files so they are added to index. All you have to do before ignoring this files you have to untrack them. 
If you want to remove them from the index you have to type `git rm -r --cached {name_folder}` then use `git commit -m "removed files from index"` and change your .gitignore file.