# .gitignore issues, doesn't ignore file

Tags: git, gitignore

My .gitignore contains the following:

```
deploy/media/customoptions/options/*/*/70x/*
deploy/media/customoptions/options/*/*/200x/*
deploy/media/customoptions/options/*/*/*/*
```

I realize this is a bit more then it really needs, but I've been testing different patterns to try to get it working.

When I run an add command:

```
git add deploy/media/customoptions/ --verbose --dry-run
```

One of the files it's matching I would like to be ignored. **Why is this being added?** Based on the path, it should match true above.

```
deploy/media/customoptions/options/998/4325/200x/200-ntlrope.jpg
```

I have tried deleting the entire .git directory and `git init`ing it again to start from a blank slate, and still adds that file.

Comment: Have you tried just using `deploy/media/customoptions/options/*` ?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `git status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works with my test using what I mentioned in my comments:

```
➜  ~ mkdir test
➜  ~ cd test
➜ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/jhvisser/test/.git/
➜  mkdir deploy/media/customoptions/options/998/4325/200x/ -p
➜  echo "test" > deploy/media/customoptions/options/998/4325/200x/200-ntlrope.jpg
➜  git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        deploy/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
➜  git add deploy/media/customoptions/ --verbose --dry-run
add 'deploy/media/customoptions/options/998/4325/200x/200-ntlrope.jpg'
➜  echo "deploy/media/customoptions/options/*" > .gitignore
➜  cat .gitignore
deploy/media/customoptions/options/*
➜  git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .gitignore

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
➜  git add deploy/media/customoptions/ --verbose --dry-run
➜
```

Therefore try just `deploy/media/customoptions/options/*`

I also tested with `deploy/media/customoptions/options/*/*/200x/*` and `deploy/media/customoptions/options/*/*/*/*` and both of these worked. These are the ones you show in your examples. You may be doing something incorrect, so give what I showed in my test a try.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't have to delete the `.git` directory to re-set ignored files. The following two commands should re-set everything and ignore the relevant pieces from the `.gitignore`:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add -A
```

That will first "remove" everything from Git and then re-add it back, obeying `.gitignore` files.

---

As far as your patterns, it appears you're attempting to just ignore everything after

```
deploy/media/customoptions/options
```

in which case you could use the [globstar](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#globstar_.28since_bash_4.0-alpha.29) pattern

```
deploy/media/customoptions/options/**/*
```

or simply just 'anything' under `options/`

```
deploy/media/customoptions/options/*
```

Remember that `*` matches directories too, and [Git supports ignoring whole directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory), so even the following should work

```
deploy/media/customoptions/options/
```

Answer (score 0):

As the answers [already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38449485/1347968) [given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38449511/1347968) describe that it should work, here are two ideas on what could have gone wrong:

1. Git ignores only *new* files. If you already had the file `deploy/media/customoptions/options/998/4325/200x/200-ntlrope.jpg` in your repository, `git add` will happily stage the changes of this file to the index. Either you remove the file from the repository (`git rm --staged <filename>`) or you tell Git to never check for modifications of this file (`git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>`).
2. Where did you put your `.gitignore`? Paths are always *relative* to the directory of this file. So you may put the file in the directory `deploy/media/customoptions/` and add `options/` to it to ignore the directory `deploy/media/customoptions/options` and all its content. Or you may put it in the root of your repository with the full path `deploy/media/customoptions/options/`.