# Cannot figure out to ".gitingore" sub folders

Tags: git

I cannot figure out how to get setup my ".gitignore" file to ignore bin/Debug and bin/Release folders for a C#.NET project.  I've researched this and tried everything imaginable.  I'm surely not understanding something fundamental.

My root folder (the one that contains the solution file, as well as my .gitignore and my .git hidden folder) has these folders:

```
ABC
EDF
GHI
```

I want to ignore ABC/bin/Debug, EDF/bin/Debug, ... etc.

My .gitignore looks like this (one example I've tried):

```
ABC/bin/Debug/
EDF/bin/Debug/
GHI/bin/Debug/
```

Yet, when I type "commit -a" it shows that all the files in those folders are "modified" and going to be committed.  Same thing if I type "git status".

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Is the .gitignore in the wrong place? Are the patterns wrong? What would be the correct pattern for this?

Comment: Already answered similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory?rq=1

Comment: If the files are showing up as *modified* (not "new") they are already being tracked and `.gitignore` will have no effect. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30210030/1256452) on the duplicate.

Comment: The answer does not work.  This is why I'm asking again.  I'll try on that thread?