# exclude a subfolder that can appear multiple times

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following source tree:

```
main_folder
main_folder/data
main_folder/subfolder1
main_folder/subfolder1/data
main_folder/subfolder1/subfolder
main_folder/subfolder1/subfolder/data
................
................
```

What's the proper .gitignore syntax, to exclude the data subfolder, wherever it appears in the source tree?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore - ignore any 'bin' directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in a `.gitignore` file you're able to `ignore` files in multiple different ways. You could exclude files by setting them piece for piece like the example below:

```
/main_folder/data
/main_folder/subfolder_1/data
...
...
```

But you're also able to select al the subfolders in a folder by using the asterix symbol like the example below:

```
/main_folder/*
/main_folder/subfolder_1/*
```

in your case you should use the following to exclude all folders with the name `data`. Example:

```
data/
```

A simulair question like yours you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/gitignore-ignore-any-bin-directory)

hope this helps!