# How to ignore a folder named a same name, that exists in many subdirectories in git?

Tags: git, gitignore

My .gitignore contains the following line

```
build/
```

And, the directory structure of my project looks like

```
/myproject
   .gitignore
   /sub_prj1
      /build
   /sub_prj2
      /build
   ...
```

However after git push, the *build* directory under all *sub_prj1*, *sub_prj2*... exists in the remote.

How can I ignore *build* directory ?

Comment: Try `**/build/*`

Comment: No, build still here

Comment: Since they have been tracked, remove them first by `git rm -- <path> && git commit`.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank you very much. It works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ignoring any 'bin' directory on a git project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/ignoring-any-bin-directory-on-a-git-project)

Answer (score 0):

From what you said

> However after git push, the build directory under all sub_prj1, sub_prj2... exists in the remote

I will suggest on your local, run

```
git rm -- <path> 

git status //to confirm you have no any other issue
```

after which you then

```
git add .
git commit -m "whatever message you choose"
git push
```

This should solve your issue.