# How to do not push unmodified local files into GIT?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm new to GIT and Branches. I've two problems with GIT

1. There are two `branches` Dev and Master, whenever we've done any modifications in Dev we are `syncing` them with Master `branch`(if required). Some time we are getting error while doing `commit` the changes in Dev, by using `pull` option we've resolved the error. While doing `pull`, `GIT` automatically merging my modifications into master `branch`. While `GIT` is configured with **Jenkins** the changes are going to Production without any approval from business.
2. Some times, other team peoples just copying other HTML pages themselves directly into prod folder(Which is also a part of GIT). So, whenever we `merge` the code with dev, the local files are replacing prod files.

Could you please anyone help on this. I'm struggling a lot since 1 week.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Stop allowing multiple developers from introducing files with the same name in the same location within your project.

Comment: What exactly is `prod` folder and why do you need it? E.g. why do you have `prod` folder in `Dev` and `Master`?

Comment: As a best practice, use branch protection rules under **Settings** > **Branches** to prevent people from directly merging their changes into the `master`, `prod` or any other critical branch. Developers must create their own feature branches from these branches and when they want to merge, create pull requests to be reviewed by code owners. See https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/GitHub-Top-10-Best-Practices/td-p/14228.

Comment: If you only want selected commits on `dev` to be added to `master` and thus into production you may need to look at a flow based on cherry picking commits. But seems like you would be better with everyone working on topic/feature branches and having an approval process via pull requests to include into `dev`.

Comment: @DibakarAditya, If i provide the rules to branch, will local files(unmodified) push to prod server or Dev server ? Or else is there any way to skip a specific folder to don't commit?

Comment: @Chanikya To prevent a file or directory from being committed, you can create a `.gitignore` file at the root of your repository and add an entry/regex to ignore them as needed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/ignoring-any-bin-directory-on-a-git-project. Then commit this file. However, note that this will ignore the directory from being committed from any machine where the repository is cloned.

Comment: In addition, if you want only the modified files to be committed and ignore the new untracked files in your local repository, use the single command `git commit -am <message>` instead of `git add .; git commit -m <message>`.

Comment: @DibakarAditya, where to enter those commands in Visual Studio?

Comment: I apparently missed that you are using the VS interface. You can just run these commands on the terminal (View > Terminal) or externally using Gitbash/command prompt.