# Ignore dags in subfolders using .airflowignore

Tags: airflow, gitignore

I have the following dir structure:

```
   .
├── project
│   ├── dag_1
│   │   ├── dag
│   │   │   ├── current
│   │   │       └── dag_1_v2.py
│   │   │   └── deprecated
│   │   │       └── dag_1_v1.py
│   │   └── sparkjobs
│   │       ├── current
│   │       └── deprecated
│   └── dag_2
│       ├── dag
│       │   ├── current
│       │       └── dag_2_v2.py
│       │   └── deprecated
│       │       └── dag_2_v1.py
│       └── sparkjobs
│           ├── current
│           └── deprecated
```

I want to ignore all deprecated folders, so I used `.airflowignore` to do that. When I place `.airflowignore`  with `*/deprecated` inside `dag_1` or `dag_2` folder, Airflow ignores the deprecated dag, like:

```
├── project
│   ├── dag_1
│   │   ├── .airflowignore
│   │   ├── dag
│   │   │   ├── current
│   │   │       └── dag_1_v2.py
│   │   │   └── deprecated
│   │   │       └── dag_1_v1.py
```

Considering this, I'll have to place a `.airflowignore` inside each dag folder. When I try to put onlny one `.airflowignore` using `**/**/deprecated` in the `project` folder the deprecated dags returns to Airflow, like:

```
├── project
│   ├── .airflowignore
│   ├── dag_1
│   │   ├── dag
│   │   │   ├── current
│   │   │       └── dag_1_v2.py
│   │   │   └── deprecated
│   │   │       └── dag_1_v1.py
```

My question is: How can I have only one `.airflowignore` in the `project` dir level to ignore all deprecated folders inside each `dag_n/dag` folder? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.airflowignore` has same logic as `.gitignore` so what ever solution applies to `.gitignore` will also work here.

I believe what you are after is just

```
deprecated/
```

on the top level.

See also [ignoring any 'bin' directory on a git project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/ignoring-any-bin-directory-on-a-git-project)